# Not able to connect with mongodb helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I have created a namespace mongodb in this namespace I deployed helm chart like this

```
 helm install mongodb --set architecture="standalone",auth.enabled=true,auth.username="mynd",auth.password="mynd321",auth.database=users,useStatefulSet=true bitnami/mongodb --namespace=mongodb-0
```

The helm chart is created and deployed, after port forwarding I can connect it with the mongodb compass. I have a python script which runs in another pod in another name space there I get this error "pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}"
follwoing is my python code

```
CLIENT = MongoClient("mongodb.mongodb.svc.cluster.local", username="mynd", password="mynd321")
```

how can I fix this error.